# Wrapping an existing socket in SSL - Python

Tags: python, ssl, starttls

I'm having some trouble wrapping an existing socket connection in ssl in a Python program. Essentially, it's an implementation of STARTTLS, i.e. a currently connected client can issue the STARTTLS command and the server will secure the connection.

Here's the portion of the code that I'm struggling with:

```
self.client_s = ssl.wrap_socket(
    self.client_s,
    certfile='/path/to/cert.crt',
    keyfile='/path/to/key.key',
    do_handshake_on_connect=False
    )
while True:
    try:
        self.client_s.do_handshake()
        break
    except ssl.SSLError, e:
        if e.args[0] == ssl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            select([self.client_s], [], [])
        elif e.args[0] == ssl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            select([], [self.client_s], [])
        else: raise
```

When I connect using openssl, I get the following:

```
_ssl.c:491: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I'm connecting by running this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:50000 -crlf -starttls smtp -debug -ssl3
```

Changing the openssl command to use `-ssl2`, `-no_ssl2`, or `-tls1` is no help. I've also tried adding `server_side=True to wrap_socket()` but just causes the ssl handshake to time-out.

I should note that `wrap_socket()` works fine when the connection is encrypted from start to finish, just not when I try to use it in a STARTTLS context.

Python version is 2.4.3

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any pointers or help.

Comment: IIRC, Python's default SSL version is "SSLv23", which tries SSLv3 and falls back to SSLv2. If you're running openssl with TLS, this won't work. Have you tried passing `-no_tls -ssl2` to openssl and explicitly specifying SSLv2 to the Python side (or any other pair of matching values)?

Comment: Probably a stupid question: are you wrapping the socket after you've received the STARTTLS or before?

Comment: @abarnert - Yes, I tried specifying -no_tls1 -ssl2, but still get the same error message.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca - The socket is wrapped after starttls, the example code is what's executed when the starttls command is received.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I asked. Did you try specifying `-no_tls1 -ssl2` to OpenSSL _and explicitly specifying SSLv2 to the Python side_ (with `ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv2`)? Just doing half of that isn't the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert - Sorry, misunderstood you. I tried again, specifying several different matching values (ssl2 / ssl2, tls1 / tls1). Still not working but I got a different error: `_ssl.c:491: error:1406D0D4:SSL routines:GET_SERVER_HELLO:read wrong packet type` I feel like it has something to do with the `server_side` argument in `wrap_socket()`, though setting that to True still has the same effect of causing the handshake to time-out