# How to secure messages travelling between a socket client and server in Python 3?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to secure messages that travel between a Python socket server and client. I have done research and found the following links:
[Wrapping an existing socket in SSL - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994949/wrapping-an-existing-socket-in-ssl-python)
[Python socket client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714386/python-socket-client-and-server)
http://the.randomengineer.com/2013/10/11/a-practitioners-overview-to-ssl-and-viewing-the-certificate-chain-from-python/

and have viewed the Python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html

But I still do not understand exactly how to do this. Most tutorials found online are referring to Apache or HTTP servers.

Here is some code that may explain exactly what I am trying to ask:

Client:

```
import socket, sys
host = 'localhost'
port = 5558
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print (str(e))
    y = input('Press enter to close')
    sys.exit()
data = 'test'
s.sendall(str.encode(data))
```

Server:

```
import socket, time
host = ''
port = 5558
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)
sock, addr = s.accept()
data = sock.recv(2048)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Look at: http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2013/1/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to simply encrypt your message with [AES](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) from [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).

Example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
IV = Random.new().read(32)
c = AES.new('abcd1234efgh5678', AES.MODE_CFB, IV)
data = c.encrypt('test')

c.decrypt(data)
```

The code is not tested.

Comment: Just read your answer - out of curiousity, why did you write 'abcd1234efgh5678' in the fourth line of your code?

Comment: The password needs to be 16 bytes.